# Why is there a difference in the deflection between the top and bottom of this truss?

Tags: structural-engineering, civil-engineering

[image]

In this truss scenario, why is the deflection of point 3 less than that of point 8? I'm assuming it has something to do with the shape of the truss. If we extend the shape we will get a circle and the radius of the top is less than the bottom but I think there's a better way to explain it.

Comment: Are the loads on points 3 and 8 equal?

Answer (score 5):

Rod 38 is in tension, and therefore it stretches.

Answer (score 2):

your diagram is color-coded, red indicates the member is in compression and green indicates the member is in tension.

A member in tension, 3-8, elongates by the amount

$\epsilon=\sigma / E \ \ \text{and in this case}\quad \sigma= 10kN/A$

$\delta L=\epsilon L$

Therefor deflection of node 8 is more than node 3.

Answer (score 1):

Bending in structures can be thought of as a combination of tension in one side and compression in the other. In a solid structure the shear forces between layers/fibers of the structure transfer the loads.

[image]

Even though you have a truss structure (not a solid), you can't escape this. The mechanism of transferring forces in trusses, is slightly different compared to solids. I.e. the forces are distributed in the structure with compression and tensile forces in the rods.

So in this particular case, is that when you apply a downward force on node no 8, the force is transferred through Rod 3-8. The force on the rod is tensile. Therefore the Rod is getting longer. What you are measuring there is the difference in length of the Rod.

**Interesting point:** if you put the force on rod 3, you would get almost the same result, however, now you would observe the opposite effect.  i.e. *the displacement of node 3 would greater than displacement of node 8*. The reason is that the same force is now compressive for the same rod.